# Django migrate does not work when a schema name is passed along with the table name

Tags: python, sql-server, django, postgresql

I have an error when I run:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

**This is the scenario:**

I have 2 schemas in my Postgres database. It could be 2 schemas anywhere, right? could be 2 schemas in SQL Server,Mysql or Oracle.

1. I want to put the default django tables in one schema and I think I was able to do it. Schema name = :django".
2. My own models in a different schema. This is where I am having problems. Schema name = "data"

My model works just fine if I do not use schema in the Meta class in my model.  To add a schema name in the db_table option you have to use "" quotes and this is the problem. You can actually create your model in the desired schema using "" quotes ("schema_name"."table_name"), but the problem comes when Django attempts to create the index of your model. PostgreSQL does not require or does not want the schema name to be passed, that is why it errors out.

I saw many posts but they assume I will use PostgreSQL forever so they suggest to use tools like tenants... blablabla which I believe it work for PostgreSQL only. The reason why I do not want to use that is because my project will not be portable anymore, what about if I want to move to SQL Server, Mysql or Oracle? I'd have to do modifications in my project and I do not want that.

I also read about using the option db_schema in my meta but it just does not work at all. It seems that Django does not recognized the db_schema attribute.

Here is my code:

Model:

```
class ClientCode(models.Model):
    client_code_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    client_code_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_inactive = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_billable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_internal = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey('companies.Company',related_name='clientcodes')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default='')


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("clientcodes:details", kwargs = {"slug": self.slug})


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('company','client_code_name')
        ordering = ['client_code_name']
        db_table = '"data"."client_code"'
        # app_label = 'company_clientcodes'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.client_code_name, self.client_name)
```

This is the Error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: CREATE INDEX ""data"."client_code"_447d3092" ON "data"."clie...
```

SQLMigrate code result:

```
BEGIN;
--
--  Create model ClientCode
--
CREATE TABLE "data"."client_code" ("client_code_id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY    KEY, "client_code_name" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "client_name" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "is_inactive" boolean NOT NULL, "is_billable" boolean NOT NULL, "is_internal" boolean NOT NULL, "slug" varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "company_id"  integer NOT NULL);
--
-- Alter unique_together for clientcode (1 constraint(s))
--
ALTER TABLE "data"."client_code" ADD CONSTRAINT     "data_client_code_company_id_e066ecc7_uniq" UNIQUE ("company_id",    "client_code_name");
 ALTER TABLE "data"."client_code" ADD CONSTRAINT  "data_client_code_company_id_bf78b136_fk_data_company_company_id" FOREIGN KEY  ("company_id") REFERENCES "data"."company" ("company_id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY  DEFERRED;
CREATE INDEX ""data"."client_code"_447d3092" ON "data"."client_code"     ("company_id");
CREATE INDEX "data_client_code_slug_d0a8e64d_like" ON "data"."client_code" ("slug" varchar_pattern_ops);

COMMIT;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide what SQL migrations generate: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate?

Comment: Hi @vanadium23. I just added it in my post. You will see the problem quickly, but how can I fix it? that is my big question. I do not think Django framework expect us to write an snippet to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same error, I had something like this:

```
db_table = "'sellers'"
```

so I changed it to

```
db_table = 'sellers'
```

and then the migration worked fine. Maybe you could try changing your code in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved it for me:

```py
class Meta:
    db_table = 'data"."client_code'
```

This way, the generated SQL is correct.